# Applying the strategy design pattern

Tags: python, design-patterns

I need to write a program for text lemmatization (different forms of words). Since I'm going to be using different lemmatization libraries and comparing them I've decided to use Strategy Pattern.

My idea is to wrap everything to single class and, depending on lemmatization function, only change my lemmatize method.

Here's my class:

```
import re
import types

create_bound_method = types.MethodType

class Lemmatizator(object):
def __init__(self, filename=None, lemmatization=None):
    if lemmatization and filename:
        self.filename = filename
        self.lemmatize = create_bound_method(lemmatization, self)

def _get_text(self):
    with open(f'texts/{self.filename}.txt', 'r') as file:
        self.text = file.read()

def _split_to_unique(self):
    text = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', self.text)
    split_text = re.split(r'\s', text)

    self.unique_words = set(split_text)

    return self.unique_words

def lemmatize(self):
    return 'Lemmatize function or text are not found'
```

Then I'm creating my lemmatize method:

```
def nltk_lemmatization(self):
words = {}

for word in self.unique_words:
    if word:
        words[word] = {
            'noun': wnl.lemmatize(word),
            'adverb': wnl.lemmatize(word, pos='r'),
            'adjective': wnl.lemmatize(word, pos='a'),
            'verb': wnl.lemmatize(word, pos='v')
        }

return words
```

And trying to apply it:

```
nltk_lem = Lemmatizator('A Christmas Carol in Prose', nltk_lemmatization)
nltk_lem.lemmatize()
```

But I receive the following error:

> ```
> for word in self.unique_words:
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'Lemmatizator' object has no attribute 'unique_words'

what's wrong?

Comment: The `unique_words` attribute is set to the object only in `_split_to_unique` which is never called before `for word in self.unique_words`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, `self.unique_words` is only added to the class in the `_split_to_unique(self)` function. So when you're calling `nltk_lemmatization(self)`, `_split_to_unique(self)` hasn't been called yet, and as a result, it tries to iterate through something that doesn't exist.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please use backticks (the same key where ~ is) to differentiate function names (and other code) inline in the answer.